# simple awk string concatenation unexpected result

Tags: string, awk

I have this file "time.txt":

```
1:53 5:38
5:46 8:17
8:19 12:37
```

and I want to use it in batch tasks, the test cmd is like this:

```
awk '{ print "ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss "$1" -to "$2" -y -c copy " }' time.txt
```

The output is like this:

```
 -y -c copy mp4 -ss 1:53 -to 5:38
 -y -c copy mp4 -ss 5:46 -to 8:17
 -y -c copy mp4 -ss 8:19 -to 12:37
```

What is wrong? (It looks like the strings are overwritten when it should be concatenated.)

**The cause found:**

The file "time.txt" has **windows-type new-line characters**, which upsets awk's work.
After converting them to **unix-type**, awk works well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks good for me

```
[/c]$ awk '{ print "ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss "$1" -to "$2" -y -c copy " }' time.txt

ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 1:53 -to 5:38 -y -c copy
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 5:46 -to 8:17 -y -c copy
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 8:19 -to 12:37 -y -c copy
```

FYI:

```
[/c]$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks. The file has problem: new-line character is windows type. It works when they are converted to unix type.